# Ionic 2 RC0 Using Google Maps

Tags: cordova, google-maps, plugins, maps, ionic2

I've created an `ionic 2` application `RC0` and i want to create a **map** into my application.

**First Step:**

Add Google Maps Plugin using CLI command line

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
```

**Seconde Step:**

Add All function and my code is :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController , Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MonzaData } from '../../providers/monza-data';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html'
})
export class Map {
  map: GoogleMap;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.loadMap();
    });
  }

  loadMap(){

        let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(-34.9290,138.6010);

        this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
          'backgroundColor': 'white',
          'controls': {
            'compass': true,
            'myLocationButton': true,
            'indoorPicker': true,
            'zoom': true
          },
          'gestures': {
            'scroll': true,
            'tilt': true,
            'rotate': true,
            'zoom': true
          },
          'camera': {
            'latLng': location,
            'tilt': 30,
            'zoom': 15,
            'bearing': 50
          }
        });

        this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
            console.log('Map is ready!');
        });

    }
}
```

**Finaly :**

Run the app using `ionic run ios` but an error has been appeared :

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/monza.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/monza.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GoogleMaps.o monza/Plugins/plugin.google.maps/GoogleMaps.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/path/monza/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,monza.xcodeproj,-target,monza,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/path/monza/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/imac/Desktop/data mac/desktop/imac-MBackUp/monza/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

 [Warning] Native: tried accessing the undefined plugin but it's not installed. (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
 [Warning] Install the undefined plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps' (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
```

**Ionic info :**

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 1.2.1
Gulp local:  
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.36
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.12.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```